# Header Image Not Scaling to Other Screens

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a `header` div. I set the `background-size: 100% 100%` but on mobile devices, it isn't scaling at all. I'd like to keep the image the same across all devices. Here is the full CSS:

```
background: url(Oly1600x600.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 600px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

I've tried using the `background-size: cover` and it zoomed the entire image in, cutting off a lot from the top and bottom. What I mean by scaling is, I would like the original image to be shown across all devices, such as desktop browser, mobile device and tablet. If it cannot be shown completely, then the image shouldn't be distorted, i.e stretched. Hope that clears some things up.

EDIT: Here's the link to the page: https://www.heroesjourney.com/olympic-weightlifting

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't scaling"? Are you expecting `background-size` to control the `div`'s size?

Comment: Is it an image element, or another element with a background image? And what do you mean by scaling? Are you talking about aspect ratio? You should probably add more details/clarity to your question if you want a reliable answer.

Comment: @DBS Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'background-size: cover;' should solve your scaling problems, i assume you want the image to fill the container without blank space and that's exactly what cover does.

Comment: I tried using background-size: cover, but it zoomed the entire image in.

Comment: Humm could you set up a jsFiddle so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Any advice on resolving the issue?

Comment: The problem is that your header height is fixed so resizing will "cut" the image on it's left and right sides there is no way around it, the only solution would be changing the header size to always have the same ratio.

Comment: Thank you for the help. How would I set the header to have the same ratio?

Comment: There are a few techniques to achieve this, imho the padding bottom one is still the best, see this article for details http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Answer (score 0):

try this: `background-size: cover;`

Comment: I tried using background-size: cover, but it zoomed the entire image in.

Answer (score 0):

```
.img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

link:-http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries
**or**

```
  #header img{ 
           max-width: 80%;
    }
```